# Using nginx to run dynamic content

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I wanna use nginx to run my node.js application. I created a build of the application and inside my nginx.conf I set the root to point to the location of the build folder. This worked and my application ran successfully on nginx.

Now I'm wondering if I could serve dynamic content directly through nginx. Like how I would get the app running with npm start can I do something similar with nginx instead of using the build(static) files?

Answer (score 1):

You need a reverse proxy.

In your application. Configure your server to run on an internal port. For example `3000`.

Then configure nginx to proxy connections to your app. Here's a simple nginx configuration to do just that:

```
root /path/to/app/build;

# Handle static content
location  ^~ /static {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

# Handle dynamic content
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}
```

Or, if you prefer, you can invert the URL scheme to default to static files:

```
root /path/to/app/build;

# Handle dynamic content
location ^~ /api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}

# Handle static content
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

---

#### Why do something like this?

There are several reasons to use an nginx front-end instead of setting your server to serve directly on port 80.

1. Nginx can server static content much faster than Express.static or other node static server.
2. Nginx can act as a load-balancer when you want to scale your server.
3. Nginx has been battle-tested on the internet so most security issues has been fixed or is well known. In comparison, express or http.server are just libraries and **you** are the person responsible for your application's security.
4. Nginx is a bit faster at serving HTTPS compared to node. So you can develop a plain-old HTTP server in node and let nginx handle encryption.

Comment: I'm pretty new to nginx so I don't really understand what this is supposed to do. 
`location  ^~ /static {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}`

Comment: That means any url that starts with /static will cause nginx to look into $root/static or $root/static/. Which means requesting `http://server.com/static/page3.html` will load `/path/to/app/build/static/page3.html` and requesting `http://server.com/static/foo` will load `/path/to/app/build/static/foo/index.html`